# What is this expression?

Tags: notation

I saw this nice relief on the University of Warsaw's library building, but I'm left wondering what the line beneath $\pi$ and above Collatz is saying. I'm not familiar with the arrow notation.

Can anyone identify it or give a reference for it?

[image]

Comment: That is the long exact sequence of homology groups of a pair $(X,A)$ of topological spaces.

Comment: Looks like Mayer-Vietoris http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayer%E2%80%93Vietoris_sequence to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the [long exact sequence of homology groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_homology#Properties) for a [pair of spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairs_of_spaces) $(X,A)$.